# cakePHP auto delete data from mysql

Tags: mysql, database, cakephp

The table has following fields: `id, date, user_id, city, price`

I would like the rows that are older than 1 year to be automaticaly deleted, but I am not really sure about how to do this. Should it be done by application or database? How?

Another issue here is that there are going to be ~50k inserts every year. What will happen to 'id' field in a couple of years? Won't the number get too large? What could be done in this case?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest [creating a basic shell](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html#creating-a-shell) that handles deleting the records, and schedule a cron job that runs whenever you wish to check for records that should be deleted. The shell could be very simple, something like this:

```
class JanitorShell extends AppShell {
    // put the model you wish to delete from here
    public $uses = array('Model'); 

    public function main() {
        $this->Model->deleteAll(array(
          'Model.created <' => date('Y-m-d', '-1 year')
        ));
        $this->out('Records deleted.');
    }
}
```

Then your cron job would run your shell. To run your shell, call:

```
cake -app /path/to/app janitor
```

This assumes `cake` is in your PATH. Of course, this is a very basic shell and could be easily expanded, keeping logs of what's been deleted or even just moving deleted records to a new table, a sort of 'soft delete'. You should probably not put such destructive code in `main()` since it runs each time you run the shell, but this will get you started.

To answer your second question, 50k inserts a year is nothing to fret about. To know the limits of your primary keys, read up on MySQL datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

actually I think it should be

date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 year'))